# Wordpress: if (url is example.com/sitemap) do this...

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string

Previously, I've been creating my sitemap page with `example.com?action=sitemap`

That allowed me to easily test on my index page for a sitemap request with...

```
$_REQUEST['action']
```

However, I'd like to instead create the link to the sitemap with `example.com/sitemap`

And I'd like to know how I can parse the request for the appearance of "`/sitemap`"

Comment: You can use htacces for this, and "redirect" /sitemap to ?action=sitemap but in wordpress it is better to create a site named sitemap and choose your sitemap template to show the sitemap, i think this is easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new rewrite rule in Wordpress something like this:

```
function sitemap_rewrite($wp_rewrite) {
    $rules = array('sitemap' => 'index.php?action=sitemap');
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'sitemap_rewrite');

function flush_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_filter('init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');
```

You should only need to run these functions once (when your theme is installed for example) because the rewrite rules are stored in the database.

However, you'll probably find that using this method you cannot access your `action` variable using `$_REQUEST['action']`. To access your variable you'll have add it to Wordpress' `query_vars` array, something like this:

```
function add_action_query_var($vars) {
    array_push($vars, 'action');
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_action_query_var');
```

You can then retrieve the action variable using `get_query_var('action')`.

Comment: In my opinion this is the correct answer, if a bit overkill for what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'sitemap')===false) {
//sitemap not found in server string
} else { 
//sitemap found in server string
}
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know Wordpress so my answer will be framework/app agnostic, but you can use mod_rewrite to easily achieve this behavior (although that means either it is already enabled on your host, either you have config-edit access). Just put this in a `.htaccess` file at your web root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/sitemap$ /index.php?action=sitemap [QSA,L]
```

If you already have a `.htaccess` file with a `RewriteEngine On` statement, you can safely include only the second line anywhere after your existing `RewriteEngine` declaration.

What it does is basically tell apache to treat all request on `/sitemap` as requests on `/index.php?action=sitemap`.

Comment: Though, maybe if he did this with PHP he could avoid .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the contents of the PHPs `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` variable. It should have your `/sitemap` part with a possibility of having some additional parameters as well.

Comment: Did you mean `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`? The `QUERY_STRING` entry is for data following the `?` caracter.

Comment: I think he misunderstood that action= would no longer be present.

Answer (score 0):

Why not: [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) or [$_REQUEST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)